# What fonts are available for LaTeX?

Tags: fonts, metafont

I have used Computer Modern, and I love it.
Is there any other complete METAFONT font that can be used with LaTeX?

Comment: You may not get many fonts which come from a METAFONT background. It's become clear over the years that designers don't really work quite that way!

Comment: I realise that your question mentions LaTeX explicitly, so you may already be aware of Xe(La)TeX and do not wish to consider it.  But just in case, Xe(La)TeX allows you to use pretty much any font present in your system.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/) provides an overview with examples and how to use them of nearly all freely available fonts with good LaTeX support.

Answer (score 7):

Essentially any font will work with LaTeX as a text font, you just have to set it up first. Math fonts are more trouble because they need more symbols. A list of free math fonts is at http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/Free_Math_Font_Survey/survey.html . There are also commercial LaTeX font sets, including all math fonts, for Times (known as MathTime) and Lucida.

There is also a program called XeTeX that is supposed to have very good support for fonts already installed on your computer. I haven't tried it, though.

Answer (score 2):

An early project to make a complete font family was [Pandora](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/pandora/), but it has never really caught on.

Comment: pandora may once have been larger than it now is, but when i looked at it, i couldn't even see complete coverage of computer modern.  (but it's a pleasing font, for all that.  whatever, i've never used it in production, and am unlikely to start now.)