# How to use different font for full document in LaTeX

Tags: fonts

I am not able to find how to call different fonts family in latex. Could someone help me out or any link will be useful.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}      
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphics} 
\usepackage{color}                  
\usepackage{hyperref}              
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\lfoot{%(full_name)s/%(emp_id)s/\thepage}
\cfoot{}
\topmargin -2.5cm
\parindent 0cm
\textheight 27.5cm
\parskip 3mm




\begin{document}
\oddsidemargin -1cm
\evensidemargin 0cm


\fontencoding{\encodingdefault}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\fontshape{\shapedefault}
```

thanks

Comment: Take a look at the answer to this [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11115/typefaces-that-come-with-the-standard-latex-distribution-on-the-tex-live). Does it help?

Answer (score 7):

To learn to apply a font to the whole document (if it isn't be default) see:

[How to make an exotic font the default through the whole document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12586/2975)

If you are looking for other fonts the best place to look is the Font Catalogue:

http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/

and/or see the following questions:

[Typefaces that come with the standard LaTeX distribution on the TeX Live](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11115/2975)

[Which LaTeX fonts can be practically considered as available on most platforms?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2814/2975)

[What fonts are available for LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1666/2975)