# Other easily available fonts in LaTeX

Tags: fonts, packages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What fonts are available for LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1666/what-fonts-are-available-for-latex)

I frequently use `\usepackage{mathpazo}` and `\usepackage{fouriernc}`, and I am wondering of other such packages that make it easy to use a different font in my documents. I am aware of the power of XeTeX, but would like to exhaust all "simpler" options first. I know the question of fonts has appeared many times, so I apologize in advance for any potential duplicates.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you looked at [what-fonts-are-available-for-latex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1666/what-fonts-are-available-for-latex)?

Answer (score 1):

Lots of fonts: 
http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/ for a list for `pdflatex`. For `LuaTeX` or `XeTeX` every system font is possible. Run `texdoc fontspec`.